# MinAbsSum: Given array of integers, find the lowest absolute sum of elements

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, for-loop, math

I get stuck with a problem in the Codility that I want to solve and also, collected a solution for the problem. The problem is provided below,

> For a given array A of N integers and a sequence S of N integers from
>   the set {−1, 1}, we define val(A, S) as follows:
>
> val(A, S) = |sum{ A[i]*S[i] for i = 0..N−1 }|
>
> (Assume that the sum of zero elements equals zero.)
>
> For a given array A, we are looking for such a sequence S that
>   minimizes val(A,S).
>
> Write a function:
>
> class Solution { public int solution(int[] A); }
>
> that, given an array A of N integers, computes the minimum value of
>   val(A,S) from all possible values of val(A,S) for all possible
>   sequences S of N integers from the set {−1, 1}.
>
> For example, given array:
>
> A[0] =  1   A[1] =  5   A[2] =  2   A[3] = -2 your function should
>   return 0, since for S = [−1, 1, −1, 1], val(A, S) = 0, which is the
>   minimum possible value.
>
> Write an efficient algorithm for the following assumptions:
>
> N is an integer within the range [0..20,000]; each element of array A
>   is an integer within the range [−100..100].

I have the solution below,

```
public static int solution(int[] A) {

    int N = A.length;

    if (N == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    int sum = 0;
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {

        int value = Math.abs(A[i]);
        sum += value;

        if (max < value) {
            max = value;
        }

        A[i] = value;
    }


    // A      = [1, 5, 2, -2]
    // A(abs) = [1, 5, 2, 2]

    // Max value = 5
    // Sum value = 10

    // counts  = [0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1]
    int[] counts = new int[max + 1];

    for (int value : A) {
        counts[value]++;
    }

    // Total = [0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
    int[] Total = new int[sum + 1];

    for (int i = 1; i < Total.length; i++) {
        Total[i] = -1;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < counts.length; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < Total.length; j++) {

            if (Total[j] >= 0) {
                Total[j] = counts[i];
            } else if (j - i >= 0 && Total[j - i] > 0) {
                Total[j] = Total[j - i] - 1;
            }
        }
    }

    int result = sum;

    for (int i = 0; i < Total.length / 2 + 1; i++) {

        if (Total[i] >= 0 && result > Math.abs(sum - 2 * i)) {
            result = Math.abs(sum - 2 * i);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Can anyone with good algorithmic skills explain to me the solution?

Comment: Good explanation here: https://codility.com/media/train/solution-min-abs-sum.pdf

Comment: Can you explain whats there instead of just pointing to the doc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It goes through the array's elements one by one. Since we're adding consecutive numbers all we need to do is to make sure, that the sum does not get smaller. That's why we take a number and check how the sum changes.

Formally we can write this the following way:

```
max(solution([a1, a2, ..., an]) = sum(abs(a1), abs(a2), ..., abs(an)),
```

where `abs` denotes the absolute value (`|x| = x * signum(x)`).

Example:

Assume we have an array [1, -2, 3]. The array of absolute values would be [1, 2, 3]. We need to find the greatest value from all combinations:

```
1 + 2 + 3
1 + 2 - 3
1 - 2 + 3
...
-1 - 2 - 3
```

Obviously because sign before each element does not affect the sum, we need to consider, if `sum + element` or `sum - element` is greater. The greatest is the sum of absolute values: `1 + 2 + 3`.

Comment: We need to find the minimum sum, not the maximum...